# Bootstrap Navbar - Extra Spaces?

Tags: text, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists, footer, navbar

I have a Bootstrap Footer that I'm making, and I'm putting images in it as icons, and also text - all as < li >s.

Where there are images - there is no space at the bottom.
Where there's text - there is. Why is that? I don't want that.

Check it out here on JSFiddle:

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/GalGreenfield/21f3sLkq/1/"></a>
```

It's the first time I've posted a JSFiddle link here, so if you mind explaining me why StackOverflow required me to use code with the link, it'd help me with future questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add `padding-top: 5px;` to your li with text like this:

```
<li style="border:1px solid blue; padding-top: 5px;"><a href="#">logo</a></li>
```

Comment: I'm going to make this all responsive, so using pixels isn't something that I want to do.

Comment: And I prefer not to hard-code em values.

Would that be the only solution?